# Number of ways of making a tangential quadrilateral such that its perimeter is $24$ and side lengths are integers from $1$ to $12$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

My attempt is as follows:

Label the sides of the quadrilateral as $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ in a counterclockwise order. Since the quadrilateral is tangential and its perimeter is $24$, $a+c=b+d=\frac{24}{2}=12$.

The number of noncommutative ways of choosing $a+c=12$ is $11$ ($1+11$, $2+10$, ... $5+7$, $6+6$, $7+5$, ... , $10+2$, $11+1$) and the same applies for $b+d$. The number of choosing two pairs to form a quadrilateral is therefore $11 \cdot 11=121$.

The number $121$ is overcounted since we counted every rotation of the quadrilateral as a new one. For example, $a = 5$,$b = 1$ ,$c = 7$,$d = 11$ describes the same quadrilateral as $a = 11$,$b = 5$,$c = 1$,$d = 7$. There are $4$ rotations, so we counted every quadrilateral $4$ times, exept the case where $a=b=c=d=6$, which we correctly counted only once. The true number is therefore $\frac{121-1}{4}+1=31$

I somehow have a feeling that this number is too low, and I suspect that there is a mistake in my reasoning for the overcounting process. Is there a better way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Are mirror images (where they are not superimposable by rotation) distinct?

Comment: @OscarLanzi No, mirror images are not considered distinct.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you over-divided the numbers. For example $(4,8; 4,8)$ is only counted twice so it should be divided by $2$ while you divided it by $4$.

The systematic way to count this is to let $a$ to be the smallest number.

$a=1: b$ has $11$ choices.

$a=2: b$ has $9$ choices (because $d\geq 2$ as well).

$a=3: b$ has $7$ choices.

And so on until $a=6$ where $b$ has $1$ choices. In this way rotation won't matter and we always get a unique combination.

Therefore totally $11+9+7+...+1=36$.

Comment: This assumes mirror images are distinct.  Should clarify the question.  If mirror images are not distinct then 21 is correct.

Comment: OP tells me mirror images are not distinct.  Please correct accordingly.  21 should be correct.